# How to export to excel columns in dataGrid which are checked by user

Tags: c#, excel

I have a dataTable in c# application which looks like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.RowSpan="2"  SelectionMode="Extended" CanUserAddRows="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  CanUserDeleteRows="False"  SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  IsReadOnly="True"    Margin="20,150,20,20" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding no}" Visibility="Hidden" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Issue ID" Binding="{Binding IssueID}" Width="0.4*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Summary" Binding="{Binding Summary}" Width="0.4*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Type}" Width="0.4*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}" Width="0.4*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Label" Binding="{Binding Label}"  Width="0.4*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Components" Binding="{Binding Components}" Width="0.4*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Empty Fields" Binding="{Binding EmptyFields}" Width="0.4*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reporter" Binding="{Binding Reporter}" Width="0.4*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Requester" Binding="{Binding Requester}" Width="0.4*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Requesting Team" Binding="{Binding RequestingTeam}" Width="0.4*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Assignee" Binding="{Binding Assignee}" Width="0.4*"/>

        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

I poulate this datagrid by downloading some jsons and parsing them. I want to export the output to excel but provide an option to the user to select the columns to export to excel. Can anyone provide a code or any reference to how this could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the solution on my own. I opened a new form when the export to excel button on this form is clicked. This new form has checkboxes for each column of the table and a button to export the checked boxes to excel. I checked each checkbox in the onclick event of the button and if they are checked then added the respective column to excel.